# Two inscribed circles in a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, circles

In a parallelogram ABCD with angle $A=60^0$, the bisector of angle B is drawn which cuts the side CD at point E. A circle $S_1$ of radius 'r' is inscribed in the triangle ECB. Another circle $S_2$ is inscribed in the trapezoid ABED. We need to find the distance between the centers of $S_1$ and $S_2$ and the common tangent length.

I proved that triangle BEC will be an equilateral triangle and that the radius of $S_2$ is $\frac{3r}{2}$. Hereafter I am stuck.

Comment: First of all, I have to say that your deduction on BEC is correct (it easily follows from the fact that the sum of the internal angles of any quadrilateral is equal to $360^o$).
Since the length of a direct (i.e., external) common tangent to two circles is given by $\sqrt{(D_{S_1-S_2})\cdot(r'-r)^2}$, we have that the final result is $\sqrt{(D_{S_1-S_2})\cdot(\frac{3\cdot r}{2}-r)^2}=\sqrt{D_{S_1-S_2}} \cdot \frac{r}{2}$. Thus, the only value that you need to find is the distance $\bar{S_1S_2}$ (i.e., $D_{S_1-S_2}$).